# Number Game based on remainder theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem

Which is the smallest number that when divided by 5 gives 4 as remainder, when divided by 6 gives 5 as remainder, when divided by 7 gives 6 as remainder, when divided by 8 gives 7 as remainder, when divided by 9 gives 8 as remainder and when divided by 10 gives 9 as remainder?

Comment: Since you've applied the tag `chinese-remainder-theorem`, you perhaps know one way to approach this problem.  One difficulty is that your specific moduli are not coprime.  Sort out some that are redundant (e.g. if dividing by $10$ gives remainder $9$, then dividing by $5$ must give $4$) and any that may be inconsistent.  Then you will be able to answer.

Answer (score 1):

We have that such number $N$ is congruent to $-1$ modulo $5,6,7,8,9,10$. Then
$N+1=\mbox{lcm}(5,6,7,8,9,10)=5\cdot 7\cdot 8\cdot 9=2520$. Hence $N=2519$.